# What is a good workflow for working with SCCS as a version control system?

Tags: unix, version-control

Due to the restrictions put in place by our organisation, we are currently limited to using SCCS for version control.

SCCS only lets one developer work on a file at the same time and this is creating bottlenecks within our workflow.

Does anyone have any examples or tips on working with SCCS successfully?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not put up with this. SCCS was cr*p when it was actually used back in the 1980s, and the idea of using it in 2010 is ridiculous. I'm speaking as someone who worked for a company training people to use the thing, back then, so I know whereof I speak. Any modern VCS will be far, far, far better, and as most of them are free, there is no possible reason for using SCCS.

Comment: I agree wholeheartedly and I'm an avid fan of Git for personal use. Do you know of any resources that I can use to persuade "the powers that be" to allow us to use something more modern like Git?

Comment: @purinkle What is their rationale for insisting on SCCS? Is it because it comes free with UNIX? If they are really hidebound I think suggesting git might be a bit much - I'd start them gently using SVN, but really anything (even raw RCS!) would be better than SCCS.

Comment: @unquiet-mind The reasoning behind not changing is that other VCSs are not in the "approved product set". If we have to go through the hassle of getting a product approved we might as go the whole hog.